# AWS Account API ListRegions function requires region to be set in the session

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, amazon-ec2

I am having an AWS account and I want to get the list of all regions using the API.

```
    accountId = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    input := &account.ListRegionsInput{
        AccountId: &accountId,
    }

    // Notice, I am not passing any region here.
    mySession, _ := session.NewSession(&aws.Config{
            Credentials: creds,
        })

    acClient1 := account.New(ac.session)
    regions, err := acClient1.ListRegions(input)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Error: %v\n", err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("Regions: %v\n", regions)
```

This gives me the error:
MissingRegion: could not find region configuration

However, the same works fine in aws-cli without providing/setting any region value.

```
>>aws account list-regions
{
    "Regions": [
        {
            "RegionName": "af-south-1",
        ....
```

Comment: `aws` command line requires region, you probably have it set in your `~/.aws.config` or in `AWS_REGION` environment variable

Comment: The region is needed so that the SDK (or awscli) knows which service endpoint to send the API request to.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't provide any region either in env or in config. I ran the aws cli command with debug and I see that it is picking the region "**us-east-1**"  when no region is specified.

```
2024-01-14 09:35:40,990 - MainThread - botocore.credentials - DEBUG - Looking for credentials via: env
2024-01-14 09:35:40,991 - MainThread - botocore.credentials - INFO - Found credentials in environment variables.
2024-01-14 09:35:40,993 - MainThread - botocore.loaders - DEBUG - Loading JSON file: /usr/local/aws-cli/v2/2.15.10/dist/awscli/botocore/data/endpoints.json
2024-01-14 09:35:41,026 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event choose-service-name: calling handler <function handle_service_name_alias at 0x7f5fe5f76160>
2024-01-14 09:35:41,061 - MainThread - botocore.loaders - DEBUG - Loading JSON file: /usr/local/aws-cli/v2/2.15.10/dist/awscli/botocore/data/account/2021-02-01/endpoint-rule-set-1.json
2024-01-14 09:35:41,062 - MainThread - botocore.loaders - DEBUG - Loading JSON file: /usr/local/aws-cli/v2/2.15.10/dist/awscli/botocore/data/partitions.json
2024-01-14 09:35:41,063 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event creating-client-class.account: calling handler <function add_generate_presigned_url at 0x7f5fe63c0180>
2024-01-14 09:35:41,074 - MainThread - botocore.configprovider - DEBUG - Looking for endpoint for account via: environment_service
2024-01-14 09:35:41,074 - MainThread - botocore.configprovider - DEBUG - Looking for endpoint for account via: environment_global
2024-01-14 09:35:41,074 - MainThread - botocore.configprovider - DEBUG - Looking for endpoint for account via: config_service
2024-01-14 09:35:41,074 - MainThread - botocore.configprovider - DEBUG - Looking for endpoint for account via: config_global
2024-01-14 09:35:41,074 - MainThread - botocore.configprovider - DEBUG - No configured endpoint found.
2024-01-14 09:35:41,076 - MainThread - botocore.endpoint - DEBUG - Setting account timeout as (60, 60)
2024-01-14 09:35:41,088 - MainThread - botocore.regions - DEBUG - Calling endpoint provider with parameters: {'Region': 'aws-global', 'UseDualStack': False, 'UseFIPS': False}
2024-01-14 09:35:41,089 - MainThread - botocore.regions - DEBUG - Endpoint provider result: https://account.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
```

Does this mean "us-east-1" is by default enabled for all aws accounts?